# Iterate Over Specific Keys in a Dictionary - Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains the following:

```
name ['Albus', 'Cedric', 'Draco', 'Fred'....] 
AGATC ['15', '31', '9', '37', ....] 
TTTTTTCT ['49', '21', '13', '40', ....] 
AATG ['38', '41', '8', '10', ....] 
TCTAG ['5', '28', '26', '6', ....] 
GATA ['14', '30', '15', '5',....] 
TATC ['44', '9', '25', '10', ....] 
GAAA ['14', '36', '41', '28', ....] 
TCTG ['12', '44', '39', '8', ....]
```

I also have an array/list called `max_matches` whose every entry is an integer meant to be checked across each of the keys (i.e. the first entry in the list should be checked across every value in the key `AGATC`, if a match found then the second entry in `max_matches` to be checked across the *corresponding* value (same position) in `TTTTTTCT`, if that's a match then the same position value in `AATG` should be compared, and so on and so forth.

My question is, then, is there any way to iterate a for loop across the values of the second key *only*, so that I could compare that with the first value of `max_matches`? I know you can use .setdefault() and then the key name to iterate across the specific values, but I want to be able to iterate across not just that specific named key's values but just the general second key's values of a dictionary. Is there any way to do that?

TLDR; is there a way to iterate across a specific key values without explicitly naming the key (i.e. only the second key values, something like `dict.setdefault(2)` for key 2 and not `dict.setdefault('AGATC'))`?

Comment: `dict.setdefault(2)` does not iterate keys ... and _Order_ and _keys of a dict_ is a very recent thing to have. Beside that ... no [mre], please [edit] and fix.

Comment: Does that mean there isn't? Sorry, I'm very new to all this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a for-loop that you can try out.

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
   if key == "AGATC":
      #compare values under this key with your max_matches
```